# How to generate a installer package for electronNET for Mac OS?

Tags: macos, electron-builder, electron.net

I have a Electron.NET app running on .net core 3. All works fine and I am able to generate a Windows .exe installer. Now I want to do the same for Mac. My questions are:

1. How do you build a installer package for Mac OS using
   "electronize build /target osx"?
2. Do you need to run this on a Mac or can this be generated on
       Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron.NET uses electron-builder. This should automatically create an installer for you after a build... otherwise you can find all the configurations on its website:
https://www.electron.build

The configuration is stored in the electron.manifest.json file under the "build" part.

p.s. use the latest electron.net version